# Copying symbols from static object into shared object

Tags: gcc, linker

I have a library, foo, for which I've produced a static object (libfoo.a).

I have a second library, bar, for which I've produced a shared object (libbar.so), which picks up some symbols from libfoo.a.

I have a third library, baz, for which I'm trying to link to bar. Upon invoking the linker, I get errors about symbols missing in bar (corresponding to symbols that are in foo). `nm` tells me that these symbols exist in libfoo.a, but not in libbar.so; however, there are some symbols from libfoo.a in libbar.so.

Why aren't all symbols being copied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `.a` library is not a "static object".  A `.a` file is an archive, similar in theory to `tar`, but a different format and generated by the `ar` command.  Each object in the archive is distinct and individual.  Usually these objects are `.o` files, which are compiled, unlinked objects.  All the symbols in one of those `.o` files would be included in another files during linking (`ld`).  But not all objects in an archive would be required during linking, the symbols in the other object files would not be seen in the linked file.

For example, in `libdialog.a`, there are `mouse.o` and `columns.o` object files.  Your program uses columns, but not the mouse functions.  So your program includes all the symbols in `columns.o`, but none of the symbols in `mouse.o` are included.

With a "shared object" (`.so`), it is a single object, so linking against it will include all the symbols in the object, needed or not.  In the example above, if we linked against `libdialog.so`, then the program would include the symbols from both `columns.o` and `mouse.o` even though the mouse based code is not used.

When generating a shared object (`.so`), the same linkage rules apply when using an archive (`.a`).  So the `.so` file will only include the symbols in the `.o` files in the archive that are used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But in my scenario, baz doesn't use anything that bar doesn't, so why is it looking for symbols that bar didn't include in its `.so`?

Comment: Without seeing the code I wouldn't be able to answer that.  The linker (`ld`) would look at the symbols that need to be resolved and look for any libraries (`.a` or `.so`) or object files that have that symbol.  The next action I'd take is to look at which symbols would need to be resolved (`nm -g`) in object files going into `libbaz.so` (`bas.o`, etc.)